# What is the total count of digits from 1 to N such that number of odd digits in the number is even and no of even digits are odd?

Tags: math, numbers, range, combinatorics

I want to count the numbers which follows above.
e.g. from 1 to 10 there are four such nos. which are 2,4,6,8.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are we to count *digits* from 1 to N or *numbers* from 1 to N? What is the proper result for, say, `N = 99` and `N = 999`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score -2):

loop the numbers from 1 to N and check if a number is even with the modulus operator (%). The remainder will be zero in a division by 2 if the number is even.

```
public class Program
{
	public static void Main()
	{
		int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
		int count = 0;
		for(int i = 1; i < N; i++)
		{
			if(i % 2 == 0)
			{
				// Even
				count++;
			}
			else
			{
				// Odd
			}
		}
		
		Console.WriteLine(count);
	}
}
```